# Backup npm packages registry

Tags: npm, backup, yarnpkg, package.json, package-managers

We are becoming more and more dependent on public open-source repositories – And I was wondering if one of the packages or dependencies is down or no longer online – we'd be screwed if we do not have a plan B.

Is there any project that allows you to scan all you Github project "package.json/yarn.lock" – and backup in your own VM all dependencies that you used for your project. That would be a failover registry in case something goes south.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self-hosted caching NPM proxy like https://verdaccio.org/ .

Install from it (forcefully) to make it cache your requested packages.

```bash
npm install --force --registry https://your.npm.proxy
```

Restore is a simple unforced

```bash
npm install --registry https://your.npm.proxy
```